# $f^2$ and $f^3$ are holomorphic implies $f$ is holomorphic. Without continuity assumption.

Tags: complex-analysis

The answer is here: [$f^2$ and $f^3$ are holomorphic implies $f$ is holomorphic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783550/f2-and-f3-are-holomorphic-implies-f-is-holomorphic) However, they assume continuity of $f$.

I just wanted to make sure that that is not necessary. Since $f^2$ is holomorphic, it is bounded around its zeroes. Thus $f$ is bounded around its zero. Hence now we can conclude that that all of the singularities are removable as $f^3/f^2$ is bounded around $f$'s zeroes. Thus it follows $f$ is holomorphic

Comment: assuming $f \ne 0$ (hence $f^2 \ne 0$) identically, $f^3/f^2$ is meromorphic so $f$ is meromorphic and then $f^2$ has no poles, so $f$ doesn't either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continuity of $f$ is indeed not needed. As you correctly said, $f$ is bounded around each zero, and therefore has a removable singularity at each zero. One has to argue carefully that the holomorphic continuation coincides with $f$.

I would proceed as follows: Assume that $f^2$ and $f^3$ are holomorphic in $D \subset \Bbb C$, and that $f$ is not identically zero.

- The set $A = \{ z \in D \mid f(z) = 0 \}$ has no accumulation point in $D$ because $f^2$ is holomorphic.
- $f = f^3/f^2$ is holomorphic in $D \setminus A$.
- At every point $z_0 \in A$ we have
  $$
   \lim_{z \to z_0}{f^2(z)} = 0 \implies  \lim_{z \to z_0}{f(z)} = 0 = f(z_0) \, .
  $$
  so that we can *conclude* that $f$ is continuous at $z=z_0$. [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) then shows that $f$ is holomorphic at $z=z_0$.

It follows that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$.

Comment: out here: "The set $A = \{ z \in D \mid f(z) = 0 \}$ has no accumulation point in $D$ because $f^2$ is holomorphic." did you mean: "The set $A = \{ z \in D \mid f^2(z) = 0 \}$ has no accumulation point in $D$ because $f^2$ is holomorphic."?

Comment: @mathman12: $ \{ z \in D \mid f(z) = 0 \}$ and $ \{ z \in D \mid f(z)^2 = 0 \}$ are the same sets.